# Setting 3 divs to display inline with floats

Tags: html, css

I have 3 divs that I would like to display inline.

2 divs on the left and 1 div on the right most on the screen.

When screen shrinks or the name size increases I want all elements to still stay inline and name to wrap on the new line if it is hitting the right div. Right div has to always be on the right. I would like to avoid using set width/height except for the images.

I cant seem to be able to this correctly.

Also Right div seems to be splitting and not staying inline no matter what I do or even disappearing.

**So expected result is: div 1&2 always left, div 3 always right and all three always inline when screen width changes**

Here is my html:

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="one">
        <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/74/GeoGebra_icon_geogebra.png" alt="" class="image">
    </div>
    <div class="two">
        <span class="name">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</span>
        <span class="title">Title</span>
    </div>
    <div class="three">
        <div class="this">
            <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/74/GeoGebra_icon_geogebra.png" alt="" class="this-image">
            <span class="this-num">12</span>
        </div>
        <div class="that">
            <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/74/GeoGebra_icon_geogebra.png" alt="" class="that-image">
            <span class="that-num">21</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

this is my css:

```
.main {
    display: -webkit-inline-box;
}

.this-image, .that-image {
    width: 16px;
}

.title, .name {
    display: block;
}

.three {
    float:right;
    position: fixed;
}

.one {
    background-color: red;
}

.two {
    background-color: green;
    margin-left: 15px;
}

.three {
    background-color: blue;

}
```

here is my jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/r679f840/1/

Thanks

Comment: Check this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r679f840/3/) and let me know if is it what you're looking for.

Comment: Is this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/r679f840/4/) what you want??

Comment: @hex494D49 almost, if you increase the text inside the name div the whole div falls down, im working with a variable screen sizes (width:320 - 960) and names can be quite large

Comment: which one is almost???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.one with float left, .with margin-right (no float) .three with absolute and no float

```
.main {
    position: relative;
}

.one {
    background-color: red;
    float:left;
    margin-right:15px;
    margin-bottom:15px;    
}

.two {
    background-color: green;
    margin-right: 46px;
 }

.three {
    background-color: blue;
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    top: 0;
 }
```

[see fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/barakedry/r679f840/7/)

Comment: thank you, one thing is that when the screen is really small the text wraps on the left under the image, should be an easy fix:)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
.main {
    display:table;
    width:100%;
}
.this-image, .that-image {
    width: 16px;
}
.title, .name {
    display: block;
}
.one, .two, .three {
    display:table-cell;
    width:30%;
    margin:0 1%;
}
.one {
    background-color: red;
}
.two {
    background-color: green;
    margin-left: 15px;
}
.three {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

[see fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/4cfwh40j/)

Comment: the text has to be 15px to the right of the image and span all the width with wrapping when hitting the right div, so thats not exactly what i need, but thanks :) i would like to avoid using percentages

Comment: @Eugene , could you show us a print of the behavior expected in both case ? short & long .two ?

Answer (score 0):

Similar answer than Fabio with `display : table;` as a basis.

Difference is to leave a gap in between second and third cell untill there is enough content to fill it.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/r679f840/5/)**

```
.main {
    display: table;
    width:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.this-image, .that-image {
    width: 16px;
}
.title, .name {
    display: block;
}
.one, .two, .three {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
.one {
    background-color: red;
}
.two {
    background-color: green;
    display:inline-table;
}
.two:after {/* here is the faux-columns revisited to draw your background if needed */
    content:'';
    display:block;
    height:1000px;
    margin-bottom:-1000px;
    background:green;
}
.three {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

[image: shrinked and not]

Answer (score 0):

Found solution to my own question myself, but @Barak your answer was almost perfect so I'll keep your answer as the correct.

Here is my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/r679f840/8/

And here is my CSS:

```
.main {
    display: flex;
}

.this-image, .that-image {
    width: 16px;
}

.title, .name {
    display: block;
}

.one {
    background-color: red;
    float:left;
}

.two {
    background-color: green;
    margin-left: 30px;
    padding-right: 60px;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}

.three {
    background-color: blue;
    float:left;
    width: 50px;
}
```